# Renaming files with the same names as directory - bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to rename my files so that they are name with the same name as the folder.

I have a main folder that has around 1000 folders. each of these folders have another file within it. in that very last folder, I have files with different extentions. and I want to rename the files that have pdb extention.

here's the strcuture of my folders :

```
pv----|

       |--m10\ pk\ result0.pdb result1.pdb result2.pdb
       |--m20\ pk\ result0.pdb result1.pdb result2.pdb
       |--m30\ pk\ result0.pdb result1.pdb result2.pdb
```

I want something like this :

```
pv----|

       |--m10\ pk\ m10_result0.pdb m10_result1.pdb m10_result2.pdb
       |--m20\ pk\ m20_result0.pdb m20_result1.pdb m20_result2.pdb
       |--m30\ pk\ m30_result0.pdb m30_result1.pdb m30_result2.pdb
```

that's the code I made but It's not working ..

```
for d in MD_PR2 / * / * / 

do

     (cd "$d" && for file in *.pdb ; do mv "$file" "${file/result/$d_result}" ; done)
done
```

my code is deleting "result" of each file's name and I don't know. it becomes 0.pdb , 1.pdb ..etc

thank you very much

Comment: The structure is unclear to me. What is your folder structure? The best would be if you would post  how to recreate the folder structure using `mkdir` and `touch`. Like `mkdir -p pb/m10/pk pb/m11 ; touch pb/m10/pk/file_in_pk_folder.pdb`.

Comment: Please use the button `{}` (in the header of the question editor) to format your code properly. Select your code blocks and click the button to make every line into "code".

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
user@pc:~$ tree
.
├── m10
│   └── pk
│       ├── result0.pdb
│       ├── result1.pdb
│       └── result2.pdb
├── m20
│   └── pk
│       ├── result0.pdb
│       ├── result1.pdb
│       └── result2.pdb
└── m30
    └── pk
        ├── result0.pdb
        ├── result1.pdb
        └── result2.pdb
```

Your code is not working because `$d_result` is being interpreted as a variable name, not as a concatenation of `$d` and `_result`. I suggest using `${d}_result`.

However I would suggest another approach, one that doesn't need to `cd` into each directory.

Code:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **; do 
  if [[ "$file" =~ ".pdb" ]] ; then 
    mv "$file" `echo $file | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\/\(.*.pdb\)/\1\/\2\/\1_\2_\3/'`; 
  fi; 
done;
```

After:

```
user@pc:~$ tree
.
├── m10
│   └── pk
│       ├── m10_pk_result0.pdb
│       ├── m10_pk_result1.pdb
│       └── m10_pk_result2.pdb
├── m20
│   └── pk
│       ├── m20_pk_result0.pdb
│       ├── m20_pk_result1.pdb
│       └── m20_pk_result2.pdb
└── m30
    └── pk
        ├── m30_pk_result0.pdb
        ├── m30_pk_result1.pdb
        └── m30_pk_result2.pdb
```

Code explanation:

- `shopt -s globstar`: Allow for `**` to be expanded into "all files and directories recursively"
- Variable "file" contains filenames including directories
- Check "file" against `"$file" =~ ".pdb"` to ignore working with directories
- Generate newfilename with `sed`:

  - Search and replace: `s/search/replace/`
  - Find something like dir1/dir2/smthg.pdb: `(.*)/(.*)/(.*.pdb)`
  - Replace with dir1/dir2/dir1_dir2_smthg.pdb: `\1/\2/\1_\2_\3` (replace with `\1_\2_\3` if you also want to move renamed files into parent dir)
  - (I removed some backslashes for readability)
- mv file to newfilename